# Can't navigate to a Group record via force:navigateToSObject

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, public-group, insufficient-privileges

I'm running into an issue while trying to open a Group record page via force:navigateToSObject in Lightning - When the event is fired, the page navigates to a page stating 'You can't view this item in Lightning Experience. Open in Salesforce Classic'. Clicking 'Open' leads to an 'Insufficient Privileges' Classic page.

- I am only seeing the behavior when attempting to navigate to a Group
  record. I have tried this with UserRole, PermissionSet, and Profile
  objects with success.
- I am running as an Admin user.

Any insights or a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no work around by doingout of the box changes.
Salesforce is not supporting in lightning it is happening with many admin activity. You may create a custom component vf page or lightning component or use the classic url with no override. or call the jsp page by creating the deeplink like below

**My lightning login gives me this :** https://trailhd-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/setup/SetupOneHome/home

**My Classic login gives me this :** https://trailhd-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp?source=lex
**Client side controller:**

```
({
    gotoURL : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.gotoURL(component);
    }
})
```

**Helper:**

```
({
    gotoURL : function (component) {
        var grpId = component.get("v.grpId"); // get your group id here
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "/setup/own/groupdetail.jsp?id=" + grpId  + "&setupid=PublicGroups"
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: This answer is kind of hard to follow, but I think you're on the right track. Perhaps you could **[edit]** it?

Comment: updated my answer